# Random Records are not displaying as expected

Tags: apex

I'm trying to display Random records and here is the Query I have written

My Apex class

```
CntC = [select count() from Case where  Status != 'Audit'];
integer rand1 = math.floor(math.random() * cntc).intvalue() ;
String queryList = 'Select Account.Name,Account.AccountNumber,CaseNumber,Anniversary_Dt__c from case where Status != \'Audit\' + ' limit:num OFFSET :rand1' ;
CsLst =Database.query(queryList);
```

Visualforce Page

```
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!CsLst}" var="Cs" >      
        <apex:column headervalue="Recertification #">
          <apex:outputLink value="/apex/HBCRecertificationDetails?id={!Cs.id}" target="_top">{!Cs.CaseNumber}
           </apex:outputLink></apex:column> 
           </apex:pageblockTable>
```

The problem here I'm facing is,

if I'm giving the **num=5** the displayed results are like this with the case number
**006886
006887
006888
006890
006891**.Only 006889 is missing and the numbers aren't randomly displayed.How can I resolve this

Comment: I don't think Salesforce return random record. It by default sort them by ID.

Comment: You'll probably want to adjust the way you generate your random offset. As is, I think your first query will eventually become non-selective. Beyond that, the maximum offset that SOQL allows is 2000 (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm ). All things considered, I think that just using 2000 in place of your `CntC` variable is probably the route I'd advise taking.

Comment: Derek F I think his random offset method is good, the problem is that the retrieved records will be contiguous. I'm afraid he can't have non contiguous records without either querying as many times as the number of records he wants, or querying the whole list of records and randomly selecting in this list. Both solutions are ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that record 006889 is not displayed because it does not exist (deleted ?).
Your code selects `num` records (or less if `rand1>(cntc-num)`) from `rand1` offset, but those records are contiguous. 
You have to write a method to randomize your list order, something like

```
List<Object> randomList = new List<Object>();
Integer index;
while (lst.size()>0){
    index = math.floor(math.random() * lst.size).intvalue() ;
    randomList.add(lst.remove(index));
}
```

(not tested, probably you would have to adjust/debug it)

Edit : 
With this solution you would still have the same 5 records but displayed randomly. If you really want 5 random records, do this (i try to make it more clear) :

```
Case[] CsLst = [select Account.Name,Account.AccountNumber,CaseNumber,Anniversary_Dt__c from case where Status != 'Audit']; // query all cases != Audit (if u don't have too many)
List<Case> randomList = new List<Case>();  //the list u will use in your VF page
Integer CnTc;   //total number of cases in your list, changing (-1) at each loop below
Integer num = 5;    //number of cases u wanna display
while (randomList.size() < num) //while you dont have the desired number in your list
{
    CnTc = math.floor( math.random() * CsLst.size() ).intvalue() ;  //generate a number between 0 and the case list size
    randomList.add(CsLst.remove(CnTc)); //remove the randomly selected case from your list from query, put it in your randomList list
}
//use randomList in VF page
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more. little bit unclear

Comment: It could also be that 006889's status is "Audit", and thus filtered out by the query. Your code snippet looks good to me.

Comment: Good point Derek.